# What is the purpose of calling `ignoret` in ATS?

Tags: ats

I often see code of the following form in ATS:

```
(ignoret(do_somthing()); do_somthing_else())
```

What is the point of calling `ignoret` in `ignoret(do_something())`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is something easily found in the official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Say you do `ignoret(foo())` where `foo()` returns an integer. As `ignoret` discards the return value, `ignore(foo())` returns void. So you can write something like:

```
(ignore(foo()); do_something_else())
```